# JQuery trigger.("submit") not working on firefox with window.print()

Tags: jquery, submit

I am trying to print a form while the submit button is clicked. But it only work on chrome and some other browsers but not in firefox. The thing I want is before submit action is executed, I want to print that form.

HTML code is something like this.

```
  <div class="container">
    <?php echo form_open('leave/add','class="printPreview"','id="toPrint"'); ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="this" onclick="doPrint()">Print Out and Request Form</button>

    <!-- Form Elements -->
    </form>
  </div>
```

Here is my code.

```
  function doPrint() {
      $("#toPrint").trigger("submit");
      $('#this').hide();
      $('#preview_btn').hide();
      $('#fill_btn').hide();
      $("#toPrint").submit(
      window.print()
      );
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, the print dialog appears but when I click print button, the submit action is not working it only print out form printer. The submit action work when cancel is clicked.

Comment: Post your html code ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this instead:

```
$("#toPrint").submit();
$("#toPrint").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    window.print();
});
```

Comment: I tried $("#toPrint").submit( window.print() ); but still not working

Comment: $("#toPrint).submit(); work. but not work with window.print() the thing I want is to print the form before submit action execute

Comment: I tried the edited code. The form is submitted but print option does not appear.

Comment: Try the new edit, in this one, the form will submit print your data and will stay on the same page. In general, as soon as you submit the form, the page reloads to the form url.

Comment: The result is still same. No, changes occur. Only the form is submitted. No print dialog.